# Android responsive scrollview

Tags: android

My question is very simple ,I am familiar with `ScrollView` but i am suffering this problem from a long time.

I have  put ten `EditText` in `ScrollView` but when i click on `EditText` my keyboard appear and then the problem start . my keyboard cover half of the screen and i am not able to scroll to the last item. I don't want my view to re size.

I want a `ScrollView` like iOS . I want my `ScrollView` to scroll to bottom and smoothly without re sizing the `View`.

Please help me with idea and code, so i can make my application cooler and nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your activity tag in the manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
```

You should also be aware of [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: I don't want to use adjustpan as its not giving me the desired one.i already used tha one.